# How to search for keywords in a txt-file and print full string out

Tags: python, list, text, txt

Hello i am using python combined with txt file and want to let my code search for parts of a word, like my txt file looks like this =

```
'www.test.com/product/wings' , 'www.test1.com/product/chicken' , 'www.okay.com/product/burger' , 'www.Test23542.com/product/smoothie'
```

So and i want to let my code open the file and search for 'www.test1.com/product/' and it should print out the complete link, included the product like = 'www.test1.com/product/chicken'

I am stuck and dont know how to do it so my current code wont really help because its just one line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://pythonspot.com/read-file/). Use [open](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open)  and then  `read` or  `readline` to read in the date in the file and then use [str() methods](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str) to find what you need,